# What is the creature on the cover of the fourth edition of 'Dinosaurs: A Concise Natural History'?

Tags: palaeontology, dinosaurs

I have yet to receive my copy so apologies if this is explained in the book - what is the creature on the cover of the fourth edition of 'Dinosaurs: A Concise Natural History'? It looks like a bird with bat wings (picture below). Could anyone put this in context and suggest why it may have been chosen as the cover image?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It appears to be of the family [Scansoriopterygidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scansoriopterygidae).**

This dead-end family in evolutionary terms, thrived in woodlands at some point between 153 and 165 million years ago. They ranged in size between small red-squirrels and large grey-squirrels, all having bat-like wings with no developed flight feathers as found in later species such as the well-known archaeopteryx.

They are thought to be marginal flyers or incapable of sustained flight, most likely gliding between trees as flying squirrels do now.

The most recent media sensation (such as it was) was of a discovery of the simply named [Yi qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_(dinosaur)), the first dinosaur ever found with bat-like wings.

> That fossil find—announced in 2015 by study co-author [Xing Xu](http://sourcedb.ivpp.cas.cn/yw/rckyw/200908/t20090811_2364085.html), the
> IVPP's deputy director—reshaped how scientists understood the
> evolution of flight.

This seems to justify its inclusion as a cover illustration.

There's a rather splendid illustration in [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/chinese-dinosaur-had-bat-like-wings-and-feathers), but I'll not reproduce it here as per their wishes. (Link will try to sell you a subscription, no affiliation with myself), however a related species [Ambopteryx longibrachium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambopteryx) is reproduced here with attribution:

[image: Dinosaur with bat-wings.]

<sup>Ambopteryx longibrachium. Artwork by Chung-Tat Cheung / Min Wang / Institute of Vertebrate Paleontology and Paleoanthropology / Chinese Academy of Sciences. 2022, [Smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/newly-discovered-bat-dinosaur-reveals-intricacies-prehistoric-flight-180972128/), fair usage.</sup>

Comment: Amazing - I had no idea